# error while building project using Nant

Tags: nunit, nant

I have file `pro.build`:

```nant
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="NAnt.NUnit2ReportTasks" default="build" basedir=".">
  <sysinfo />
  <target name="nunitreport">
    <nunit2report out="HTML_TestResults.html">
      <fileset>
        <includes name="NUnitTestResult.xml" />
      </fileset>
    </nunit2report>
    <echo message="HTML Test report generated." />
  </target>
</project>
```

From command prompt(DOS), I am giving command,

> Nant -buildfile:pro.build

But I am getting error

> Target 'build' does not exist in this project

Can you help me resolving this?

Comment: The [documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/running-nant.html) may help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `<project>`'s `default` attribute you specify the target which should be executed if no other target is specified on the command line.

Problem: On the command line you're calling `Nant -buildfile:pro.build` so you are not specifying a target there. NAnt tries to execute default target `build` which is not present and fails.

Solution: Either you specify target `nunitreport` on the command line by calling `Nant -buildfile:pro.build nunitreport`. But since specifying a non-existent default target in your build file doesn't make much sense, I would suggest changing the default target:

```
<project name="NAnt.NUnit2ReportTasks" default="nunitreport" basedir=".">
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifing complete path for the buildfile could resolve the issue

> nant –buildfile:"c:\FolderpathofAppdotbuildfileGoesHere\buildfilename.build"